# Consume Web API from .NET Console App

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, console-application

I'm getting the following error while consuming a MVC 4.0 Web API from a .NET 4.5 Console App.
"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'IEnumerable`1' from content with media type 'text/html'."
Please help!
Below is my code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:30151/");

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        //List all Customers
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/customers").Result;

         if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var customers = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Customer>>().Result;
            foreach (var c in customers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}\tName: {1}\tAddress: {2}\tEmail: {3}\tPhone: {4}", c.id, c.name, c.address, c.email, c.phone);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
        }

        Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting the content type of your posted data to 'application/json'  If your content type is 'text/html' the server won't interpret it properly

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Answer (score 0):

Your client code looks fine.  I suspect the server is not returning what it should.  Use fiddler to actually see what is being returned by the server.